# Is it possible to create an MQTT API to serve as a third-party API for other developers?

Tags: mqtt, network-protocols, iot, api-design, coap

Is it possible to create an MQTT API service for being consumed by others?

If yes, how can I do that and would that be of any use?

If no, why? Maybe it is possible to set up an API using some other IoT-specific protocol (like CoAP or something else)?

I thought that it would be useful to persist the sensors' data and the data generated by other IoT devices in some cloud for being processed and analyzed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It already exists.

Look at things like [Xively](http://xively.com) as a dashboard for MQTT data or the IBM's [IoTF](https://internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/) and Amazon's [AWS IoT](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/what-is-aws-iot.html) offerings